# c++ time_t going back before 1/1/1970

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, time-t

i have a c++ code by which i can compute/manipulate starting from an input excel date (by manipulate i mean i can increase/decrease the input date by specific increments or do other computations on it).

i use the variable time_t in my code. accroding to msdn documentation time_t is the number of seconds elaspsed since 01/01/1970. so given an input date i first compute the elasped seconds since 01/01/1970, store it in a time_t vcariable and later use localtime() for all other computation.

my code works fine as along as my input date is more than 01/01/1970 but breaks down for dates before that.

question: is there any other variable or structure using which i can go before 01/01/1970. or is there a way to manipulate the time_t variable to go before 01/01/1970.

thanks in advance

i start with 02/01/1970. i want to decrease the month by 2. first i use

```
void localtime(int* py = 0, int* pm = 0, int* pd = 0, 
            int* ph = 0, int* pn = 0, int* ps = 0,
            int* pwday = 0, int* pyday = 0, int* pisdst = 0) const
{
    struct tm* ptm = ::localtime(&t_); 
    if (py) *py = ptm->tm_year + 1900;
    if (pm) *pm = ptm->tm_mon + 1;
    if (pd) *pd = ptm->tm_mday;
    if (ph) *ph = ptm->tm_hour;
    if (pn) *pn = ptm->tm_min;
    if (ps) *ps = ptm->tm_sec;
    if (pwday) *pwday = ptm->tm_wday;
    if (pyday) *pyday = ptm->tm_yday;
    if (pisdst) *pisdst = ptm->tm_isdst;
}
```

then i use: maketime(y, m + count, d, h, n, s); where y=1970, m=2, count=-2, d=1 (from the output of the above code. the maketime() is as follows:

```
void maketime(int y, int m, int d, int h = 0, int n = 0, int s = 0)
{
    struct tm t;
    t.tm_year = y - 1900;
    t.tm_mon  = m - 1;
    t.tm_mday = d;
    t.tm_hour = h;
    t.tm_min  = n;
    t.tm_sec  = s;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;

    t_ = ::mktime(&t);
}
```

this results in t_ =-1.

now on this result i call localtime() again and

```
     struct tm* ptm = ::localtime(&t_);
```

the first line inside localtime() fails when t_ = -1.

Comment: You know there is no way to manipulate the time_t variable to go before 01/01/1970 because the documentation tells you that.

Comment: `time_t` is a signed value so I don't understand what problems you're having. Can you be more specific?

Comment: hi Mark i have updated my post with the code i am using. and described where i fails.

Answer (score 3):

`FILETIME` is similarly based on an integer count, 100-nanosecond intervals in this case, and it goes all the way back to 1601.

After seeing your edit, the problem seems simple: you need to make sure all of the elements of the [`tm` struct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) are within bounds. When you add or subtract months, you need to adjust until the month number is between 0 and 11. This is the case whether you're using `time_t` or `FILETIME`.

```
while (m < 0)
{
    m += 12;
    y -= 1;
}
while (m > 11)
{
    m -= 12;
    y += 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what will happen if the day exceeds the number of days in a month, for example if you try to subtract 1 month from March 31.